# Building Win32 platform dll on VS2008 WIN7 64 Bit

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, dll, regsvr32

When I try to build a Win32 platform C++ DLL, I get the error: 
Error   22  error PRJ0050: Failed to register output.  Please try enabling Per-user Redirection or register the component from a command prompt with elevated permissions.

When I try to regsvr32 the dll itself using the 32bit regsvr32 in the WOW64 folder with "Run as Admin", I still get the error message:

"The module "xx" failed to load. Make sure the binary is stored at the specified path or debug it to check for problems with the binary or dependent .dll files. the specified module could not be found.

But if I choose the platform to be x64, It registers just fine.

What I am trying to accomplish is to build compatibility for both Win7 64 and WinXp for both execution and development.

Any advice on how to solve this issue? Thanks!

Comment: can you check if any other dependencies of module "xx" are missing?

Comment: "Debug it" is excellent advice.  Right-click the project, Properties, Debugging, Command = `regsvr32 "$(TargetPath)"`

Comment: How do you check if any other dependencies of module is missing? Thank you Matt.

Comment: @user2584960: http://www.dependencywalker.com/

Comment: It says MFC90D.DLL MSVCR90D.DLL IESHIMS.DLL not found. However the same project built fine on the Winxp Machine.....  I did disable manifest generation on the Win7 Machine because it was crashing the incremental linker...


Update: I disabled manifest generation on the WinXp, now its having the same problem. So the root cause is that the incremental linker crashing on Win7....

Comment: It is fixed, after I reinstalled VS2008 with all updates.